# Total download size of *initial* page of major websites

Tags: filesize

I'm quite surprised how large some major websites homepages are.
This is the total amount downloaded just when opening the homepage.

```
cnn.com - 845kb
microsoft.com - 470kb
yahoo.com - 235kb
gillette.com (flash) - 3.8Mb
abc.com - 3.4Mb
nbc.com - 1.4Mb
youtube.com - 530kb
```

Anyone care to add to the list? I'm just trying to justify the size of a site by comparing it to major sites out there. Obviously some of these sites are quite media intensive and wouldn't be much fun at 200kb. Im quite surprised how huge some sites actually are.

To do this I used [fiddler](http://fiddlertool.com). **Clear your cache first**, go to the site, select all the items in fiddler and under the 'statistics' tab it will show the total.

Comment: This is trivia, not a programming related question. Really, it's not.

Comment: i agree. probably something programmers should be more aware of though. i bet most developers on a site couldnt tell you how big their homepage was (if they have one as such). programmers should care more about this. i dont mind the downvote - if it was you )

Comment: i should have called it 'what is the maximum size a homepage ought to be, before you lose significant visitors' - or something like that

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't need another site to justify the size of yours. Just because your site is not as big as, say, nbc.com, does not mean that the size is ok. You should still be trying to make it as small as possible.

Comment: its more about peoples reaction when they hear the size. people automatically assuming its too big. plus i assume that these large companies have made somewhat of a fair judgment (with the exception of my gillette example. 4mb is just plain crazy)

Comment: true, but your site can be too big even if it's smaller than other large companies' sites. I see your point though - sometimes it's just about offsetting initial reactions.

Comment: i also threw this out there because its just kind of a fun exercise. apple.com is acually very small when you look at what they have. its by no means intended to be scientific.